# Shuffle cards in database in java

Tags: java, database

I need to program a simple card game for final work. So, I have database with cards (each card has ID, name, type, sub-type, mana, energy, effect,attack). I connected to BD with java class (public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException), now I need to shuffle cards to begin the game - shuffle with ID. And I dont know how. 
I hope this is the way to ask help. :/

I goggled, but no help. (I 'm terrible with programming, I'm designer..)

Comment: That's not how you would do it. Just pull all the cards from the database and shuffle them in the application.

Comment: Have to agree with Sotirios. I haven't designed Magic-type games, but I have cranked out some French deck games before. You will pull a row from the database and construct a Card object based on that data. After instantiating the Card, you'll add it to an ArrayList (deck). After you've added all necessary Card objects, you will then perform your shuffle.

Answer (score 1):

If you store your cards in an ArrayList, it's trivial.

```
private ArrayList<Card> cards;

// add your cards however you like

Collections.shuffle(cards);
```

Take a look at the [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) and read up on Java Collections and data structures.